# spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:0.1.1 get token error invalid_client

Tags: java, spring-boot, authorization, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

i'm using spring authorization server, but i cannot get token.
This is my code and example. pls help me know correct request

```
@Bean
public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId("client")
            .clientSecret("secret")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_JWT)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.PRIVATE_KEY_JWT)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.JWT_BEARER)
            .clientSettings(clientSettings -> clientSettings.requireUserConsent(true))
            .build();
    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
}
```

This is my request with basic auth client/secret

> curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token' 
> --header 'Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==' 
> --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
> --header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=557C0348994EFC10DB8E7F06C2FDFF21' 
> --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'

response 401:

> {
> "error": "invalid_client"
> }

Comment: aren't the client id and password missing in you request ?

Comment: @Kaizokun i use basic authen. Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA== is client/secret

Answer (score 0):

You can try upgrading `spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server` to newer version **0.2.0**

I ran into the same problem with `client_secret_post`, but then upgrading the version works for me.

Comment: i cannot find version 0.2.0 ? 
0.1.2 is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

What is the **groupId** of the artifact you are using? `0.1.2` appears to be the latest version of the `groupId = org.springframework.security.experimental`

If you change your groupId to `org.springframework.security` you'll see version `0.2.2` and higher